# VSTS - Work Items

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

In VSTS, I am using SCRUM template for my project. I have couple of queries here.

1. How can we assign a single task to two users? Can we have two 'Assigned To' fields on the Tasks?
2. How can we add Start Date and End Date to Epics, Features and Backlog Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first query, you could add a custom field with `Allow assigning to groups` selected. In this way, you could assign to a group:

[image]

[image]

Useful link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-field?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks @Cece Dong for your response.I created a custom template and added two fields 'Owner 1' and 'Owner 2'.  It seems serve the purpose.

Comment: My queries might seems unusual but our scenario is bit different and team structure and how they are working is bit complex. If you can share your email id, I'll give more details and may be then you can suggest how we can manage in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't. Work items are completed by individuals. If you have a task that is so large that it needs to be completed by two people, it should probably be decomposed into smaller tasks that can be accomplished by an individual, or turned into a PBI and then decomposed into tasks.
2. Work items don't have start and end dates. They are organized into [iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts), which have start and end dates. Epics and Features are intended to span multiple iterations; Epics and Features have a "target date".